# Connected Devices Platform Service

Tags: windows-10

What does the `Connected Devices Platform Service` do?

I encountered an issue with high CPU and disk usage and decided to disable this service (2 similarly named services, to be exact). It seems like everything works, but I would like to know if disabling this service is likely to cause issues in the future.

For more background, I encountered this issue after doing a fresh windows 10 reinstall. Unfortunately I noticed this issue only after installing a bunch of different things and configuring stuff. So I don't know if this issue was present on the fresh system or if it was caused by something I did after the reinstall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From April 2018, Windows 10 implemented the **Timeline** uttility, which logs the activity the computer has had for the past 30 days. It contains a registry of documents editted, images viewed or created, applications launched, etc...

You can see your own timeline registry by pressing **Windows + Tab**.

Local registry can be found @ the following directory:

```
%AppData%\..\Local\ConnectedDevicesPlatform\
```

Disabling this service, as far as I have seen, only prevents Windows from logging this information. Namely, it prevents you from using Timeline feature. You could acheive this same behavior by disabling this feature on the configuration menu.

More about this, on Microsoft's site. [ [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4230676/windows-10-get-help-with-timeline) ]